# How to roll back a previous version of a TFS project?

Tags: tfs

Somehow I checked in a version of a web project that deleted an entire folder (with subfolders and ASP.net files). I want those files back, I can sacrifice the latest check-in because I can easily replicate it again.

How do I tell the TF server to roll back to the version just before the current one?

Comment: See [this previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607/how-to-rollback-using-tfs) on StackOverflow.