# Visual Studio with Azure Devops Repository -- Reverting changes to previous change set is not affecting pending changes

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, tfvc

I am using AzureDevOps with Visual Studio 2019.

I used the "Advanced" menu to get a particular changeset, but the resulting fileset is *NOT* showing the changes (i.e. the older version files) in "Pending Changes".

Is there a way to either:

a) have the previous versions of the files show in "Pending Changes"

```
--or--
```

b) just eliminate the changesets since the one I wanted

```
--or--
```

c) 'promote' a previous changeset to the 'head').

NOTE:  There have been 6 or 7 changesets since the one I wanted, and if I try to use "rollback" more than once, there is a "conflicting versions" error...

Comment: I was able to do this 'manually' by 'stashing' changes in a folder elsewhere and noting the notifications for the "get" when getting the changeset version .  Thankfully, there weren't all that many changes.  Still, it's not a good thing that this basic functionality doesn't seem to work, at least on the system that I am using.

Comment: There appears to be a way to roll back multiple change sets. 
 Since I solved my particular problem, I haven't tested it.  It is at this web-site(currently): 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/roll-back-changesets?view=azure-devops

Comment: See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607/how-do-i-rollback-a-tfs-check-in?rq=1